# Coffeescript not iterating through entire object

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I am attempting to create a function to request information about a Country ID in our database via `ajax`, because that is how the data is represented in the `address` table I query. That is, in the `address` table, the `id` of the country and not the country name is represented, and the actual country name is in another table that I query.

After I send the `ajax` request, I create a string of the address I get. However, it's only updating the last value of the object and not all of them. Here is my coffeescript:

```
requests = Array()
for key, val of {'Correspondence_Country__c':data['Correspondence_Country__c'], 'Country_of_Residence__c': data['Country_of_Residence__c']}
        console.log(key)
        console.log(val)
        requests.push($.ajax
                url: window.location.pathname
                type: 'post'
                dataType: 'json'
                data: 'search_id=' + val + '&search_column=Id&sobject=Country__c&columns=["Name"]'
                error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
                        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown)
                success: (c_data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
                        data[key] = c_data['Name']
                        console.log(c_data['Name'])
                        console.log(key)
        )
defer = $.when.apply($, requests)
```

I omitted the `defer.done` function. The result of the console.log information is as follows:

```
China P.R. 
Country_of_Residence__c 
China P.R. 
Country_of_Residence__c
```

instead of being the expected

```
China P.R. 
Correspondence_Country__c
China P.R. 
Country_of_Residence__c
```

Is there an issue with my Coffeescript?

**EDIT**: It looks like it's something to do with the `ajax` requests or pushing the `ajax` requests to the `requests` array. I added a couple `console.log()` at the beginning of the function before I pushed the `ajax` call, and it produced the following information:

```
Correspondence_Country__c
a063000000CZoZHAA1
Country_of_Residence__c
a063000000CZoZHAA1
```

Comment: [Loops are expressions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) in CoffeeScript so you could say `requests = for key, val of ...` instead of using `requests.push` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was looking earlier on how to delay a function until all of my ajax requests finished, and I used the Stack Overflow example I found. I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous (unless told otherwise, but you don't want to). Which means the loop will end before the ajax call is done. And when that ajax call finally end, "key" will be the last value of the array. (JS doesn't have block-scoping).

Use coffee's `do` to keep the correct value.

```
for key, val of {'Correspondence_Country__c':data['Correspondence_Country__c'], 'Country_of_Residence__c': data['Country_of_Residence__c']}
  do (key) ->
    # your code
```

Comment: I'd probably throw `val` into the `do` as well. The way `val` is used means that you don't need to but doing so might avoid some puzzled looks down the road.

Comment: Well, as val is not used asynchronously (and there's no obvious reason to), I'd rather avoid capturing more than needed.